# Garbled string output

Tags: c, arrays, string, stdio

I'm currently working on an assignment which asks me to censor words of argv and input redirection.

My problem is obvious in my output which can be found below. I have a lot of tracing print statements which may or may not help you point out my issue.

My intention is:

1. Get `file.txt`
2. Copy contents of `file.txt` into `buffer[x][y]`, where `[x]` is a string of word and `[y]` is a char of `[x]`.
3. Compare `argv[]` arguments to `buffer[][]`.
4. Create `newstr[size2]`. For every `argv[]` arguement found in `buffer[][]`, replace it with `replace[9] = "CENSORED"`.
5. Print the string of `newstr[0 to (size2-1)]`.

Here is my code:

```
// censored.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 128

int main ( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char buffer[SIZE][SIZE];
    char x;
    int count = 0;
    int size1 = sizeof(buffer);
    int size2 = 0;
    char replace[9] = "CENSORED";
    int buffersize=0;
    printf("tracing: size1: %d.\n", size1);
    printf("tracing: argc: %d.\n", argc);
    while((fscanf(stdin, "%c", &x)!=EOF))
    {
        if(isalpha(x))
        {
            buffer[i][j]=x;
            printf("tracing: buffer[%d][%d]: %c\n", i,j, buffer[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        else if(isspace(x)) // if whitespace
        {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            buffer[i][j]=x;//this should be buffer[i][j]
            printf("tracing: buffer[%d][%d]: %c\n", i,j, buffer[i][j]);
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else if(ispunct(x)) // if x is a punctuation
        {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            buffer[i][j]=x;//this should be buffer[i][j]
            printf("tracing: buffer[%d][%d]: %c\n", i,j, buffer[i][j]);
        }
        else if(iscntrl(x)) // if control key (\n, \r etc...)
        {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            buffer[i][j]=x;//this should be buffer[i][j]
            printf("tracing: buffer[%d][%d]: %c", i,j, buffer[i][j]);
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else if(isdigit(x))
        {
            buffer[i][j]=x;//this should be buffer[i][j]
            printf("tracing: buffer[%d][%d]: %c\n", i,j, buffer[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    size2 = i;
    printf("tracing: buffer[8][0]:%s\n",buffer[8]);
    char newstr[size2][SIZE];
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
//  tracing:
    printf("tracing: line 72\n");
    printf("tracing: size2: %d.\n", size2);
    while(i < size2) //print buffer[]
    {
        printf("%s", buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("tracing: line 80\n");
    for(k=1; k < argc; k++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[k]);
    }
//  end tracing
    i = 0; //reinitialize i
    j = 0; //reinitialize j
//  creating newstr[SIZE] and censoring words
    printf("tracing: line 89\n");
    for(i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j < argc; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(buffer[i], argv[j])==0)
            {
                strcpy(newstr[i], &replace[0]);
                printf("tracing: replaced at [%d]\n", i);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(newstr[i], buffer[i]);
                printf("tracing: copied at [%d]\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0; //reinitialize i
    while(i < size2)
    {
        printf("%s", newstr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming I have input redirection file named `file.txt` and its contents:

```
Said Hamlet to Ophelia,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of pencil shall I use?
2B or not 2B?
```

my input is:

```
./censored Ophelia thee 2B < file.txt
```

this is the weird output I got:

```
Said Hamlet to CENSORED, Ill draw a sketch ???)ofoQ? ?"h?CENSORED,2oQ?
What? /oQ?kind? of 6oQ?pencil +oQ?shall ?"h?I-oQ? ???)use? ???2BoQ?
7oQoroQ Qnot 1oQ?CENSORED?4oQ?
```

Any help is appreciated, I know my code is messy, this is my first semester learning C.

Comment: Your .txt file is definately in Ascii format, right?

Comment: `buffer[i]` isn't NUL-terminated. Try changing `char buffer[SIZE][SIZE];` to `char buffer[SIZE][SIZE] = {'\0'};`

Comment: Can I ask what output you expect? that'll help understand what exactly you intend to do and there might be easier ways to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good and bad news, the bad one is: I found a few errors and mistake.
The good one is: all of these are common for a beginner!

First one: The strings in `buffer[]` aren't terminated with a `'\0'` which is the end of string indicator. This is the one cause of your problem.
And here are the other ones:

- char buffer[SIZE][SIZE];
  Here you are considering that number of words and word's length can't be longer that 128 which will cause Segmentation Fault whenever this condition is wrong. I suggest you learn about dynamic allocation (malloc()).
- for(j=1; j < argc; j++) If argc == 1, you won't enter this loop which would result in `newstr` being empty. Usually we end arrays with a NULL pointer and then check for every string of the array being non-null while reading the array so that we won't try to use undefined content.
- As you pointed at, your code is quite messy, next time, try separating your code in functions and not coding in `main()`.
- Try reducing this, the fewer lines your write, the easier your code is to read and debug:

`j = 0;
            i++;
            buffer[i][j]=x;//this should be buffer[i][j]
            printf("tracing: buffer[%d][%d]: %c\n", i,j, buffer[i][j]);
            j = 0;
            i++;`

- This advice isn't really relevant for that kind of program designed to read a lot of data but remember: try to avoid storing data whenever you can.

I think this is enough for now, I wish you good luck and to apologize for my poor English.

Comment: @noobcoder If your code works well, don't forget to accept the answer.